# CiviMail permissions missing?

Tags: civimail, permissions

Within the CiviCRM_navigation table / Navigation Menu UI, it shows the permissions needed to access a navigation link.

I see the 'Mailings' navigation permissions parameters of:

- access CiviMail
- create mailings
- approve mailings
- schedule mailings

Within https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Faccess%2Fwp-permissions&reset=1, only *access CiviMail* exists. Where did these come from and should they be available?

CiviCRM 5.35.2, WP 5.7.

Replicated on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question. They appear to only be visible when the drupal module `rules` is enabled and you check the box on the civimail component settings. Or more precisely, these criteria:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/43a25f50080c6c9eed7afb0fe1c48a642196c920/CRM/Mailing/Info.php#L170-L183

```
    if (!$config->userSystem->is_drupal ||
      !function_exists('module_exists')
    ) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    if (!module_exists('rules')) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    $enableWorkflow = Civi::settings()->get('civimail_workflow');

    return $enableWorkflow && $config->userSystem->is_drupal;
```

[image]